# Как отобразить коллекцию в index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

При попытке вывести из БД данные `:projects` и `:todos` на локальном сервере получаю вот такой результат:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, не понимаю, в чем проблема. Мне нужно вывести список тудушек внутри каждого проекта.

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Задачи</h1>
  <% @project.each do |project| %>
    <h2><%= project.title %></h2>
    <p><%= project.todos %></p>
  <% end %>
```

projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @project = Project.all
  end
end
```

project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todos
end
```

todo.rb

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем-то, что просите

```
<p><%= project.todos %></p>
```

то и получаете. Проект связан с тудушками "один-ко-многим", то есть в `project.todos` лежит коллекция тудушек этого проекта. Рельсы вам её и показывают, используя метод `to_s`, можете в консоли вызвать `project.todos.to_s` и проверить.

Чтобы это работало, тудушки надо перебрать и отобразить аттрибуты каждой - так же, как вы с проектами делаете

```
<% @project.each do |project| %>
  <h2><%= project.title %></h2>
  <% project.todos.each do |todo| %>
    <h4><%= todo.title %></h4>
    <p><%= todo.description %></p>     
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```